# MVC 4 Bundling File Changes - Does it Recompile? Does it lose session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

MVC 4 preaches the usefulness of minifying and bundling your javascript and css resources.

Does anybody know if changing a bundled file will either cause a recompile or drop currently active sessions the same way as changing localized resource would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since bundled files are content files like CSS and JavaScript files, changing one of those is certainly not going to require a recompile nor will it drop active sessions. However, it will require clients to download a new version of the bundle on subsequent requests.